# Journey to the West / fire mountain

Tags: culture

This question is not precisely about language, but really more cultural. It is about Journey to the West/西遊記. I am doing my Chinese homework, which is to summarize the chapter of 西遊記 where 唐僧 et al. need to get the real banana leaf fan from the Iron Fan Princess to put out the fire to cross the fire mountain. I'm confused about one aspect of the plot. Is it 孫悟空 or 豬八戒 who takes the appearance of 牛魔王 in order to get drunk with 鐵扇公主 and get the real fan?  According to [the English-language Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Journey_to_the_West_characters#Bull_Demon_King.2C_Princess_Iron_Fan_and_associates), it is 孫悟空. However, I thought in class the professor said it was 豬八戒.  So I'm a little confused.  Thanks in advance for any clarity, and sorry if this question not being specifically about language is inappropriate for this forum.  -紐約市唐納文上

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia is right.

> Sun Wukong disguises himself as Bull Demon King to deceive Princess
> Iron Fan and takes away her Banana Leaf Fan. The real Bull Demon King
> visits Princess Iron Fan, who then realises she has been tricked. Bull
> Demon King disguises himself as Zhu Bajie to trick Sun Wukong and
> retrieves the fan.

From the [novel](http://www.xiexingcun.com/Xiyou/01/mydoc061.htm):

> 好大圣，即现本象，将金睛兽解了缰绳，扑一把跨上雕鞍，径直骑出水底。到于潭外，将身变作牛王模样，打着兽，纵着云，不多时，已至翠云山芭蕉洞口，叫声：“开门！”那洞门里有两个女童，闻得声音开了门，看见是牛魔王嘴脸，即入报：“奶奶，爷爷来家了。”那罗刹听言，忙整云鬟，急移莲步，出门迎接。这大圣下雕鞍，牵进金睛兽；弄大胆，诓骗女佳人。罗刹女肉眼，认他不出，即携手而入。
>
> The splendid Great Sage then reverted to his original form, untied the
> golden-eyed beast, leapt into the carved saddle, and rode straight up
> from the bottom of the water. Once out of the pool he made himself
> look like the Bull Demon King. Whipping on the beast he set his cloud
> moving and was soon at the mouth of the Plantain Cave in Mount
> Turquoise Cloud.
>
> “Open up!” he shouted, and at the sound of his voice the two servant
> girls inside the gates opened them for him.
>
> Taking him for the Bull Demon King they went in to report, “Madam, His
> Majesty's come home.” At the news Raksasi quickly neatened her hair
> and hurried out on her little lotus feet to meet him. Climbing out of
> the saddle the Great Sage led the golden-eyed beast inside. He was
> bold enough to try to deceive the beauty, whose mortal eyes failed to
> see who he really was as she led him inside, hand in hand.

Comment: OK, many thanks Songyuanyao!  This helps me out a lot.